Pandoc 3: Obtain and modify the default context for Markdown to HTML conversion in Hakyll 4?
I am currently playing around with Hakyll and Pandoc.
I want to create a static HTML website from Markdown sources including inline maths in LaTeX. Using pandoc-katex I was able to do the conversion with the following command:
$ pandoc -f markdown -t html --filter pandoc-katex --css "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@$(pandoc-katex --katex-version)/dist/katex.min.css" --css "https://pandoc.org/demo/pandoc.css" --standalone -o output.html input.md

However, I want to use the pandoc-katex filter in Hakyll and obtain the exact same result as with the command above (for now), i.e. I want to use Pandoc's standard HTML template, make it load the two CSS files and process any available metadata in the input.md in exactly the same way as the command above does.
I exported the standard HTML template as follows:
$ pandoc -D html > default-template.html

Using pandocCompilerWithTransformM, I was able to use the pandoc-katex filter:
katexCompiler = pandocCompilerWithTransformM defaultHakyllReaderOptions (defaultHakyllWriterOptions) katexFilter
  where katexFilter = recompilingUnsafeCompiler
      . runIOorExplode
      . applyFilters noEngine def [JSONFilter "pandoc-katex"] []

Using this compiler in Hakyll, I only get the body part of the HTML file though. I searched online for solutions to this, but all the information that I find seems to refer to deprecated versions of Pandoc. Apparently there was a writerStandalone option in earlier versions of Pandoc, but it does not exist anymore (even though the command line tool still has opStandalone and the --standalone parameter used above evidently works).
What I currently do is, I apply the default template with loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default-template.html" myCtx and then try to manually replicate the default context in myCtx. This is obviously not how it should be done.
Here is a somewhat minimal example of my attempt (sorry that it's still a bit lengthy - exactly that is the problem):
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Text.Pandoc
import Text.Pandoc.Filter
import Text.Pandoc.Scripting
import Hakyll

css1Item   = Item (fromFilePath "css/katex.min.css") "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.4/dist/katex.min.css" 
css2Item   = Item (fromFilePath "css/pandoc.css") "https://pandoc.org/demo/pandoc.css" 
authorItem = Item (fromFilePath "general") "Jon Doe"

stylesString = "/* 15 lines of CSS */"

myCtx :: Context String
myCtx = dateField "date" "%B %e, %Y"
       <> constField "pagetitle" "My Title"
       <> constField "styles.html" stylesString
       <> listCtx "author" [authorItem]
       <> listCtx "author-meta" [authorItem]
       <> listCtx "css" [css1Item, css2Item]
       <> listCtx "header-includes" []
       <> listCtx "include-before" []
       <> listCtx "include-after" []
       <> defaultContext

listCtx :: String -> [Item String] -> Context String
listCtx name lst = listField name ctx (return $ lst)
  where ctx = field name (return . itemBody)

katexCompiler = pandocCompilerWithTransformM defaultHakyllReaderOptions (defaultHakyllWriterOptions) katexFilter
  where katexFilter = recompilingUnsafeCompiler
      . runIOorExplode
      . applyFilters noEngine def [JSONFilter "pandoc-katex"] []

main :: IO ()
main = hakyll $ do
  match "templates/default-template.html" $ compile templateBodyCompiler
  match "input.md" $ do
      route   $ setExtension ".html"
      compile $ katexCompiler
                >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default-template.html" myCtx

I have a two concrete questions:

The Item data type associates keys  of type Identifier with values. The constructors for Identifier suggest that the Identifiers should be file names, but for some of the Items in my context, (e.g. for the author field; see variable authorItem), having a file name as a key does not make sense. I think I misinterpreted the purpose of this type. How should I think of these Items?
Is there a way to obtain the Context that the command line tool uses, when making the conversion? The default Context seems to be a lot more involved than my quick draft, e.g. it reads the abstract from the metadata of the Markdown file and puts every paragraph in between separate <p> ... </p> HTML tags. I know there is a metadataField :: Context a, but it does not seem to be what I want.

Apart from these concrete questions, the general question is:

Do I do this right at all or would there be a much simpler way of doing what I try to do (i.e. replicating the output of the initial pandoc shell command in Haskell with Hakyll)?


On writerStandalone no longer existing, you can nonetheless specify a template through the writerTemplate option. It's not clear that would be significantly better than your approach, though.

(It might actually be better, though, as in principle Pandoc would handle all those fields without you having to bother with defining them in a Hakyll context. I say "in principle" because I haven't tried to rely on writerTemplate to this extent in a Hakyll site.)

Thanks for your comments. Yes, I would prefer to just use getDefaultTemplate "html" or something like that to get the template, but I'm still trying to figure out how to do it. My current attempts do not type check yet.

ghc says "No instance for (PandocMonad Template) arising from a use of ‘getDefaultTemplate’", when I try setting {writerTemplate = Just (getDefaultTemplate "html")}. I don't see what the problem could be. The type of the writerTemplate field should be Maybe (Template Text) and getDefaultTemplate has type Text -> m Text. Any ideas?

The type of getDefaultTemplate is PandocMonad m => Text -> m Text so you need to run that with, for instance, runIOorExplode.

Oh, yes. My bad ... that's why it doesn't type check.

Ok, so I've figured out how to use getDefaultTemplate, but eventually I will want to adjust the template anyway, so I should probably stick with my current approach. Setting all the variables appropriately is still a mystery though :D Thanks for your help, @duplode!

The nicest way to do that is probably using writerTemplate in Pandoc's WriterOptions to pass the default template, as given by compileDefaultTemplate:
main :: IO ()
main = do
    pandocTmpl <- runIOorExplode $ compileDefaultTemplate "html"
    let katexOpts = defaultHakyllWriterOptions
            { writerTemplate = Just pandocTmpl
            , writerHTMLMathMethod = KaTeX ""
            -- And whatever else you need.
            }
        -- Defining it this way because pandocCompilerWith strips
        -- the metadata block before handing the body to Pandoc.
        --
        -- I'm relying on Pandoc's built-in KaTeX support. If
        -- you'd rather stick with the pandoc-katex filter, you
        -- can use renderPandocWithTransformM to reshape the
        -- compiler you defined in the question in this fashion.
        katexCompiler = do
            fullItem <- getResourceString
            renderPandocWith defaultHakyllReaderOptions katexOpts fullItem

    hakyll $ do
        -- etc.
        match "input.md" $ do
            route $ setExtension ".html"
            compile katexCompiler

See also pandoc issue #10209, which points to a similar approach.

Side questions:

How should I think of these Items?

Item indeed is primarily meant for things bound to a file path in your site tree. Occasionally, it makes sense to use a fake path for the identifier — for instance, when synthesising some content with a create rule. However, that's not typically something one would want to do for the sake of setting a context field, as there likely are more straightforward ways to do that. (In particular, if, unlike in this answer, you are using Hakyll's templates, you don't have to explicitly define the fields that you include in the metadata headers of your source files, as Hakyll's defaultContext covers that already by including metadataField.)

Is there a way to obtain the Context that the command line tool uses, when making the conversion?

While Pandoc offers ways to manipulate its own metadata (which I have never used myself; Text.Pandoc.Writers.Shared might be a good place to start browsing), the template systems of Pandoc and Hakyll are similar-looking but distinct, and in particular Hakyll's Context type is not the same as its Pandoc counterpart.

On a final note, it is worth mentioning that if you were completely stuck trying to reproduce Pandoc's output within Hakyll, a last resort would be using unixFilter to set up a compiler that shells out to command-line Pandoc.

Thank you for your answer. This is a much neater way of using the default template, I'll upvote that. It does not fully answer my question though. I need to load the two CSS files (I want to precompile KaTeX) and process the metadata. While the defaultContext processes some metadata, it does not seem to process metadata that is given as lists (e.g. author:\n- Author 1\n-Author 2), in particular author, header-includes, etc.. Other lists (e.g. author-meta) are generated from the author field by the command line tool - this is also not done by defaultContext or metadataField.

This might of course just be a bug ... maybe I should report it.

@user11718766 [1/2] In principle, this solution uses neither Hakyll's defaultContext nor your myCtx. The idea is that, by specifying writerTemplate, you let Pandoc do the template substitutions and metadata handling. Hakyll's system of templates and contexts is not involved at all.  (I did catch something missing from my answer: using pandocCompilerWith to define katexCompiler won't work, as it will strip the metadata block before delivering the contents to Pandoc. I have edited it to provide an alternative).

[2/2] As for the CSS files, you can specify them through the (list) css metadata variable, which corresponds to --css on the command line.

Ah, nice. Yes, I was confused, because your previous version did not handle the metadata. This one perfectly answers my question. Thank you so much!
